# To enter the correct mob number and dob

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

To enter the correct mob number and dob we have to check the code in progres

Answer (score 1):

Use `LENGTH(STRING(mobnum))`. This will convert it to a character string and give you the length of it. You can check to see if it is 10 characters long.

Answer (score 0):

Making minimal changes to your approach, something along these lines should work:

```
define var mobnum as  INT64 label "Mobile No:" format "9999999999" .

update mobnum.

if mobnum >= 1000000000 and mobnum < 10000000000 then 
  do:
    display "Correct number".
  end.
 else
  do:
    display "enter exactly 10 digits please".
    update mobnum.
  end.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LENGTH(mobnum) to get the quantity of digits into the number... like:

This make possible to create separate message for each of the lengths of mobnum.

```
DEF VAR mobnum AS INT NO-UNDO FORMAT "9999999999" INITIAL "99999999".
DEF VAR ii     AS INT NO-UNDO.

ii = LENGTH(mobnum).

CASE ii:
    WHEN 9 THEN DO:
        DISPLAY "Number OK".
    END.
    OTHERWISE DO:
        DISPLAY "Number is not 9-digit long".
    END.
END CASE.
```

But if you want to make it simple, just use:

```
DEF VAR mobnum AS INT NO-UNDO FORMAT "9999999999" INITIAL "99999999".
DEF VAR ii     AS INT NO-UNDO.

ii = LENGTH(mobnum).

IF ii = 9 THEN DO:
    DISPLAY "Number correct".
END. ELSE DO:
    DISPLAY "Number incorrect".
END.
```